# php array find duplicates from first array and use the key to find sum the second array

Tags: php, arrays

```
first Array
(
    [category1] => 2
    [category2] => 3
    [category3] => 1
    [category4] => 3
    [category5] => 1
)

second Array
(
    [q1] => 5
    [q2] => 23
    [q3] => 3
    [q4] => 1
    [q5] => 5
)
```

Expected outcome where it uses the duplicated values from first array to sum the values in second array, then sort it using the unique value of first array. Can somebody please gives me some ideas how to achieve it?

```
new Array
(
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 24
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$array1 = [
    'category1' => 2,
    'category2' => 3,
    'category3' => 1,
    'category4' => 3,
    'category5' => 1,
];
$array2 = [
    'q1'        => 5,
    'q2'        => 23,
    'q3'        => 3,
    'q4'        => 1,
    'q5'        => 5,
];

$output = array_fill_keys(array_unique($array1), 0);
array_map(function($a, $b) use (&$output){ $output[$a] += $b; }, $array1, $array2);
sort($output);

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => int 5
  1 => int 8
  2 => int 24
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot for your great effort!